# Insert very large array of ints into Oracle DB with OCI, long SQL statements

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am taking over an OCI application in which I need to insert a sequence of 1414 integers into a table. The previous writer of this application basically built SQL insert statements dynamically of the form

`INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (<COLUMNS...>) VALUES (<VALUES...>)`
via a sequence of strcpys, sprintfs, strcats, etc.
and stored in a statically allocated buffer `char insertStatement[BUFLEN]` where BUFLEN takes whatever size is necessary.

The statement is then prepared and executed using

```
OCIStmtPrepare(...);
OCIStmtExecute(...);
```

This has worked fine so far; however now 
I have a table with a column of type `SDATA_ARRAY` defined as

```
create or replace TYPE     SDATA_ARRAY 
AS VARRAY(1414) OF integer;
```

and need to somehow insert 1414 short ints into this table via OCI. Attempting to use the in-place strategy of building literal SQL statements fails here because the resultant string is around 6000 characters in length, and attempting to execute it yields the error

`Error msg: ORA-01704: string literal too long`

So I clearly need to change the strategy here, and anyways using strcats in this manner is actually an injection vuln. So the solution from what I can tell is to use binding. I've been going through Oracle's OCI documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci05bnd.htm#LNOCI050, and sort of understand how to bind to primitive data types. However, I can't figure out how to use a function like `OCIBindByName()` with a user-defined `VARRAY` type. I want to try something like the following:

```
unsigned short sdata[1414];
...
strcpy(insertStatement, "INSERT INTO TABLE(SDATA) VALUES (SDATA_ARRAY(:sdata));");
OCIStmtPrepare(stmthp, errhp, (text *) insertStatement, (ub4) strlen(insertStatement), 
               (ub4) OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);
// OCIBindByName(stmthp, &bindp, errhp, (text *) ":sdata", (sb4) strlen(":sdata"), 
//               sizeof(sdata), ???, ...);
OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmthp, errhp, (ub4) 1, (ub4) 0, (OCISnapshot *) NULL, 
               (OCISnapshot *) NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

obviously making sure to check errors for each call.

- What do I use for the `ub2 dty` parameter in OCIBindByName(), used to specify the type of variable being bound? (as opposed to SQLT_STR, SQLT_INT, etc.) Will I need to make additional OCI calls?
- Is there a better way to make this insert statement (using strictly OCI) that will not cause me to get a length error? Perhaps incrementally?
- Is there a better way to store these 1414 integers than a VARRAY type? (Not really in my power to change besides talking to the DBA, however...)
- Finally, will using a binding call even allow me to get past the length error?

**I have no experience with SQL, Oracle, or OCI prior to this project, the only reason it was given to me is because I'm the most comfortable with C here. Thus, any advice/criticisms/alternative ideas relevant to what I'm attempting to do are much appreciated!**

**EDIT**: This page http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci03typ.htm seems to imply that the type constant for VARRAY is SQLT_NTY for "named datatypes", putting it in the same category as objects and nested tables. However, SQLT_NTY appears to map to structs in C code, whereas my data is stored in an array of shorts. I would think that this means I have to wrap the array in a struct in order to get this to work, maybe using the Oracle's Object Type Translator. Still not sure what the bind statement will look like, however, and whether I need to add additional steps such as OCIBindObject().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to do muck around with user-defined datatypes such as this one, OCI must be initialized in object mode: `OCIInitialize(OCI_OBJECT, ...)`

Binding the array to the statement takes a bit of extra work. The solution I eventually pieced together (through a lot of searching and backtracking) has the general form:

```
OCIArray *array = NULL;
OCIType *tdo = NULL;
OCIBind *bndp = NULL;

char *typeOwner = "OWNER"; // Whichever user owns the type definition
char *typeName = "SDATA_ARRAY";

OCITypeByName(envhp, errhp, svchp, (text *) typeOwner, strlen(typeOwner),
              (text *) typeName, strlen(typeName), NULL, 0, 
              OCI_DURATION_SESSION, OCI_TYPEGET_HEADER, &tdo);

OCIObjectNew(envhp, errhp, svchp, OCI_TYPECODE_VARRAY, tdo, NULL, 
             OCI_DURATION_SESSION, TRUE, &array);

for ( int i = 0; i < 1414; i++ ) {
    OCINumber num_val;
    OCINumberFromInt(errhp, sdata[i], sizeof(unsigned short), 
                     OCI_NUMBER_UNSIGNED, &num_val);
    OCICollAppend(envhp, errhp, &num_val, NULL, array);
}
OCIStmtPrepare(stmthp, errhp, statement, strlen(statement),
               OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, OCI_DEFAULT);
OCIBindByName(stmthp, &bnpd, errhp, ":sdata", strlen(":sdata"), 
              NULL, 0, SQLT_NTY, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);

OCIBindObject(bndp, errhp, tdo, &array, NULL, NULL, NULL);

OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmthp, errhp, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

OCIObjectFree(envhp, errhp, array, OCI_OBJECTFREE_FORCE);
```

(I've not included error checking/handling for brevity's sake but it's there.)

This solution first fetches the custom data type (`OCITypeByName(...)`) and creates an instance of it. Next, Oracle provides a set of functions to operate on generic collections (such as VARRAYs or nested tables), so I used one (`OCICollAppend(...)`) to iteratively load my data into Oracle's datatype for representing VARRAYs, `OCIArray`.

Next, I prepare the statement as per usual and call `OCIBindByName(...)` with `SQLT_NTY` as the type code. From what I gather, this is the code used for **any** custom data type. This must be followed by a call to `OCIBindObject(...)`, which takes care of some extra work required for user-defined objects.

Using these steps I was able to successfully insert data. It's probably not the optimal solution but figured I'd post what I've learned in case anyone has the same problem (since the OCI documentation is a giant tangled mess), or in case anyone can suggest improvements.